# Sound issue after system update

Tags: release-loki, updates, system, sound

After installing the system updates via AppCenter the speakers do not sound.

Unfortunately [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/1608/7495) solution is not valid today.

Is there any chance to overcome this issue?

Because of I'd tried it before and realized that the system updates cause some problem on my laptop, after fresh Elementary OS installing, I use my laptop 3 days without any issue.

Then I got the system updates again. Now the speakers do not sound.

And only `Dummy Output` seems on the sound settings page.

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

**Edit:** My soundcard manufacturer is Realtek. But I cannot find model number on Elementary OS or BIOS screen.

[image]

Comment: This may not solve it but try: `sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio pavucontrol `

Then open pavucontrol go to the configuration tab and check what options you have there.

Comment: I had done this before I re-installed Elementary OS. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I can confirm this issue, a reboot helped for me, had this 2 times in 2 months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I've downgraded the linux kernel to get rid of this issue:

`sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic`

Now my kernel version is `4.4.0-38-generic` and there is no any sound issue.

Not: At the same time I had been experiencing a shutdown issue. Also it solved!

Comment: I purged `4.8.0-58`, which took me to `4.8.0-52` and I have back panel audio now (no front panel, though).

Comment: Front audio problem fixed by increasing volume and unmutting the headphone (pressing M).
Front mic doesn't show up in System settings -> Sound, but works as shown in `sudo pavuncontrol` (needs to be installed first).

Answer (score 0):

Today my speakers are working.

But I had experienced that sometimes there is no sound at all. Sometimes the sound comes from only left speaker.

And sometimes everything is OK like the picture below which is happened today.

So actually my issue is continueing because it works unstable for me.

[image]

Comment: If the sound comes from one speaker is just that your speakers are broken or because you've set the volume balance to only the left speaker.

Comment: @Maccer , unfortunately the issue is not so clear. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

having the same issues, sound work on earphones but not on laptop speakers, and even through the HDMI port I got only video not audio, tried downgrading linux kernel without success.  This did the trick for me

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-media/+question/24639

read carefully before attempting anything on your system.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I've overcome the issue but I cannot get audio via HDMI too. So I'd try your solution.