# Sound output device suddenly not recognized (loki 0.4 stable)

Tags: release-loki, sound

I just started using elementary OS and I ran into some problems.
First time I installed elementary OS, my sound was working for a while but then stopped.
I updated all packages, tried some stuff from Ubuntu forums but didn't work.
So I reinstalled elementary OS, and my sound was working as expected.

Unfortunately, after a while this happened again. My audio input/output devices are not recognized. (not even in pavu control).

Reinstalling ALSA or rebooting didn't work.

I'm using some integrated Intel audio card on a new Lenovo laptop (i5 kaby lake cpu). Not using dual boot. elementary OS is my only system.

I have been debugging this for a long time, but I didn't succeed. Please help!
Every answer is much appreciated.

Comment: There might have been a kernel update, can you try with the last but one (or another) linux kernel?

Comment: Related: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9502/sound-issue-after-system-update

Comment: Tried to downgrade my kernel. After rebooting, not even wifi driver seems to work :/

Comment: I uninstalled eOS, but now my output sound device isn't recognized even in Windows. I'm using new Lenovo 510s laptop. Maybe the issue is with something else? (BIOS or firmware or...?) I would really appreciate any answear since I'm completely desperate and Lenovo support isn't rly helping. :/