# No Sound for no reason

Tags: release-loki, intel, audio

I don't know why, but I have no sound.

Only speakers, when I plug a jack it's work.
My speaker are working on windows (dual boot)
I don't realy know what I need to do.

```
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 0: ALC233 Analog [ALC233 Analog]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Device 1d72:1501
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 279
    Memory at b1128000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b1110000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT : This bug append when I upgraded my PC :

```
Upgrade: procps:amd64 (2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2.2, 2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2.3), libprocps4:amd64 (2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2.2, 2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2.3)
```

Comment: Did you select the device wanted in _Sound Settings_ / _Play sound through_?

Comment: Yes, I have only one device.

Comment: But there should be a switch headphones / speakers

Comment: Not for me, the switch is automatic.

Comment: I had the similar issu and I get rid of the issue with downgrade the kernel - http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/9542/7495 - but it may cause another problems. Maybe...

Comment: nothing changed (I uninstalled the 4.4.0-53-generic and I currently run the 4.4.0-38-generic)

Comment: My sound issue was solved. After a system update or by the following command I don't know `sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base linux-image-'uname -r' libasound2 alsa-utils alsa-tools`   Previously `aplay -l` gives the result of `aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...` but it seems resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Sound is very intermittent. Check the link below. It seems to have fixed my sound issue, for now.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS

Comment: Did not work. I think the problem is a recent update of procps, how I can istall a previous version for test ?

Answer (score 1):

An update has been released this afternoon and it's work now.

Comment: ... An update has been released this mornig and it does not work now ... thank's eOS.

Comment: It's not eOS because it doesn't effect everyone.